# What is the evolutionary advantage of being embarrassed?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, performance, evolutionary-psychology

What I am trying to understand is why do I feel embarrassed in certain situation.

E.g. when I'm talking to people, why do I think about being judged or sounding stupid that would result me in embarrassment. I have been considered as "intelligent" since I was a kid and may be making or looking stupid goes against my own belief of me being 'intelligent'?

Also, when I'm playing a game or playing music, I think about embarrassing myself, making mistakes and think what may the audience/team mates thinking about me? So I avoid it and when I actually get a chance of play, I make mistake and regret/punish myself mentally for making a mistake or regret quite a bit. So, basically, this results me in being low confident.

I'm thinking about "impressing people" and me resulting in an embarrassing situation, acting stupid, sounding stupid would spoil my "impression". 
However, I want to act stupid or sound stupid sometime and be ok with it. 
Somehow my biology/mind prevents me every time and I feel the resistance.

So, in search of understanding the reason, I wanted to ask if this has any evolutionary benefit or is it part of natural selection? E.g. having a better chances of survival, when you express less/ be quiet or shy, so that others are not threatened by you?

Can anybody with more knowledge shed some light or possibly guide me to help my situation?

Thanks for reading a long post!

Comment: What if there is no benefit per se and is merely a side effect of something that does confer a benefit e.g. social cognition, theory of mind.

Answer (score 5):

Marks and Nesse investigated evolutionary causes of anxiety disorders and reported about embarrassment in particular:

> Social threats evoke responses that promote group acceptance, for
>   example, submission to dominants and to norms of dress, mien, odor,
>   speech, customs, beliefs. **This prevents dangerous extrusion from the
>   group. Mild shyness and embarrassment can promote acceptance.** If
>   shyness and embarrassment are excessive, however, then fitness
>   suffers, as in several anxiety disorders: pervasive shyness in
>   avoidant personality disorder; gaze aversion and fear of scrutiny, of
>   shaking, and of blushing in social  252 I. M. Marks and R. M. Nesse
>   phobia; fear of excreting near others in sphincteric phobias (Marks
>   1987, pp. 362-371); terror of looking or smelling abnormal in
>   dysmorphopho- bia; fear of behaving antisocially in
>   obsessive-compulsive disorder. Impulses to behave in ways that would
>   cause social rejection may arouse general anxiety without the subject
>   being aware of those punishable impulses, thus helping to conceal them
>   from others (Nesse 1990). We do not emphasize a distinction between
>   fear of specific dangers and anxiety aroused by nonspecific dangers or
>   unconscious impulses, because in all cases the state, whether anxiety
>   or fear, is aroused by a cue that **indicates a threat to reproductive
>   resources.**

*Nesse, Randolph M. "Fear and fitness: An evolutionary analysis of anxiety disorders." Ethology and sociobiology 15.5-6 (1994): 247-261. https://doi.org/10.1016/0162-3095(94)90002-7*

Comment: Is there any indication as to how one can overcome? I believe the normal anxiety or natural shyness that nature has selected for the "survival" do not so much come in a way, however the excessive do. And I wanted to understand what could be the reason for "excessive shyness"?

Comment: Exposure therapy: https://www.anxietycanada.com/sites/default/files/FacingFears_Exposure.pdf There's positive feedback loops in reinforced avoidance.

Comment: Thanks. I have heard that one before. Is there any other therapies beside ET and CBT?

Comment: Yes, progressive muscle relaxation, abdominal breathing, mindfulness approaches etc.But they can be used simultaneously with ET.